# Помогите с реализацией шапки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как реализовать треугольные фоны и картинку с наложением затемненную?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Руками и кодом (z-index, position, фигуры или svg). Или топорный вариант в виде здоровенного фона в jpg.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на скорую руку.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.pre {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.pre .bg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/0MKl9YD.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pre .bg::before,
.pre .bg::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.pre .bg::before {
  border-width: 100vw;
  border-bottom-width: 50vh;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pre .bg::after {
  border-width: 50vh;
  border-top-color: #cd092d;
  border-right-color: #cd092d;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.pre .bike {
  display: block;
  height: 70vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h5SQzM0.png" class="bike">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *интересует фон с затемнением и красный треугольник* – verstak44444

Это можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента, например.

```
.header__bg:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header__bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1200/e/6d/mountain-gory-nebo.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 40%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 40%, 0% 100%);
}

.header__bg:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.header__red {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ce092e;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}

.moto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url('https://pngimg.com/uploads/motorcycle/motorcycle_PNG3136.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 580px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.container img {
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header__bg"></div>
  <div class="header__red"></div>
  <div class="moto">
    <h1>Помогите с реализацией шапки</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://pics.loveplanet.ru/10/foto/90/45/90456597/e6Eo1~6gRfaDvV3yn6A==_.jpg?p=s_"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://pics.loveplanet.ru/10/foto/90/45/90456597/e6Eo1~6gRfaDvV3yn6A==_.jpg?p=s_"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://pics.loveplanet.ru/10/foto/90/45/90456597/e6Eo1~6gRfaDvV3yn6A==_.jpg?p=s_"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас 2 части: основной блок с картинкой(на него наложи затемнение) и треугольники с матоциклом в виде изображения. Тут 2 варианта:

1. Если это одна целая картинка(мотоцикл + треугольники) то нужно ей присвоить `z-index: 2` Чем больше значение, тем выше находится элемент по сравнению с теми элементами, у которых оно меньше. А основному блоку с картинкой, как вы могли догадаться, поставить`z-index: 1`.
2. Если это 4 разных части(картинка + белый треуг + красный треуг + мотоцикл), то по такому же правилу присваивайте им значения z-index и размещаете по нужным местам с помощью
   position([Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/position)).

---

[Здесь](http://xandeadx.ru/blog/css/788) есть отличные примеры создания overlay(затемнение фона) при помощи css.

Comment: интересует фон с затемнением и красный треугольник

Comment: @verstak4444 ответ вам дали, что не устроило?